Can't resolve DNS when connected to WireGuard
I need help figuring out what I did wrong with my setup.
My main compose file:
name: homelab

networks:
  main:
    name: main
    external: true
    driver: bridge
  wg_network:
    name: wg_network
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.8.1.0/24

secrets:
  cf_dns_api_token:
    file: ${SECRETSDIR}/cf_dns_api_token

include:
  - compose/dns/traefik.yaml
  - compose/dns/pihole.yaml
  - compose/dns/wg-easy.yaml
  - compose/services/uptime-kuma.yaml

My PiHole compsoe:
services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "82:80/tcp"
    hostname: pi.hole
    environment:
      - TZ=${TZ}
      - WEBPASSWORD=${PIHOLE_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKERDIR}/data/pihole/etc-pihole:/etc/pihole
      - ${DOCKERDIR}/data/pihole/etc-dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      main: {}
      wg_network:
        ipv4_address: 10.8.1.3
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.rule=Host(`pihole.${DOMAIN}`) && (PathPrefix(`/admin`) || PathPrefix(`/api`))"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.tls.certresolver=cloudflare"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.middlewares=secure-headers@file"
      - "traefik.http.services.pihole.loadbalancer.server.port=80"

And wg-easy:
services:
  wg-easy:
    container_name: wg-easy
    image: ghcr.io/wg-easy/wg-easy
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - WG_HOST=${DOMAIN}
      - PASSWORD_HASH=${PASSWORD_HASH}
      - WG_DEFAULT_DNS=10.8.1.3
      - WG_DEFAULT_ADDRESS=10.8.0.x
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKERDIR}/data/wireguard:/etc/wireguard
    ports:
      - "51820:51820/udp"
      - "51821:51821/tcp"
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
    networks:
      main: {}
      wg_network:
        ipv4_address: 10.8.1.2
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wg-easy.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wg-easy.rule=Host(`wg.${DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wg-easy.tls.certresolver=cloudflare"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wg-easy.middlewares=secure-headers@file"
      - "traefik.http.services.wg-easy.loadbalancer.server.port=51821"


I can resolve from within my wg-easy container
> docker exec -it wg-easy nslookup google.com 10.8.1.3
Server:     10.8.1.3
Address:    10.8.1.3:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.250.75.142

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4028:805::200e

I even see traffic in my wg-easy UI, yet I still can't resolve <service>.domain.com when I test it on my phone. Or even google.com.
I can however ping 8.8.8.8 while connected, so it seems like a DNS issue.
Some more WG related things:
wg show
> docker exec -it wg-easy wg show
interface: wg0
  public key: MYOSylsghbaB7SmXuK6ZCX0Zuia6HiW62GEDplX6iW0=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: nAz7erPfcxf0UEUFsBWfDkGbvyE5quPWvC1owztplS4=
  preshared key: (hidden)
  endpoint: 2.53.160.215:33853
  allowed ips: 10.8.0.2/32
  latest handshake: 4 minutes, 36 seconds ago
  transfer: 410.81 KiB received, 7.58 MiB sent

IP Route
> docker exec -it wg-easy ip route
default via 172.18.0.1 dev eth0
10.8.0.2 dev wg0 scope link
10.8.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.1.2
10.8.1.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.1.1
172.18.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.4

Any help debugging this would be appreciated.
Tried deleting everything from scratch, pruning docker networks.
